# Booting up Overwatch stuck on blank screen?

Tags: overwatch, battle.net

Yesterday there was a new patch for Overwatch, **patch 1.25.0.1**, after updating it today I get stuck on a blank screen when booting up the game.

1. Tired uninstalling and reinstalling Overwatch
2. Even uninstalled and reinstalled Blizzard Battle.net just in case.

Neither made a difference, I am still stuck on the blank screen.

- Has anyone had a similar issue?
- How did you solve it?

Comment: A "didn't work" usually does not help, can you please post your system specifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem for ~6 months now, PTR and Live.

I have a Windows 10 box, and what I do when I encounter this is

1. Create a new Desktop (using Windows+D)
2. Open up Task Manager in the new desktop
3. End the Overwatch and Battle.net Launcher processes
4. Open the Launcher and try again

I've had to repeat this process 6-7 times sometimes before it works, but it always eventually works.

Comment: Just tired that didn't work.